# Extend MDM solution for OSX

Tags: macos, mdm

I have succesfully developed a MDM platform for iOS devices as BYOD solution for my organization. However, i can't find any resources or reference on how to extend this MDM capabilitis to OSX devices as per what has been done by AirWatch and Mobile Iron for example.

Anybody care to share resources/reference?

Or i am required to purchase OSX developer account to access such documentations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this document (it's not exactly what you are looking for, but quite close)
http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_osx_configuration_profiles.pdf

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful but I'm still wondering if the detailed MDM for OSX specific technical documents are only available once enrolled with Mac Developer Program?

Comment: I am not sure. I didn't find anything interesting except this document and I don't have access to Mac Developer Program. My guess would be that OS X supports exactly the same MDM protocol only with more limited configuration profiles/restrictions.

Comment: Yes it does support exact MDM protocol but with slight different payloads. I have successfully enrolled OS X to my MDM server. However, all commands were not entertained by the device.

It's a pain just to find the documents defining the payloads. Anyways, your help did save lots of my time from roaming blindly in google :P